# Django - How to dynamically add scripts/classes to the code?

Tags: python, django

I have a `Django` project where users can register and add their XML/CSV feeds.

What the project does is (everyday morning):

1. download the feed
2. parse the feed and store it to the model `Product`
3. generate XML/CSV export from these products in a different format

Now the problem is that `users` can register anytime during the project lifetime and many feeds have to be either downloaded, parsed or exported in a specific way.

So I need to be able to react quickly when the feed is added and write custom functions/classes/scripts to download/parse or export these sources.

Let's say it would be enough to add or extend some base classes like `Downloader`,`Parser` or `Exporter`

I'm looking for the most common way to do this.

I tried multiple approaches. For example, I've created a package `parsers` and there is a `__init__.py` with `CHOICES` attribute. When a user adds new feed, I create a `parser__sourcename.py` file which I add into `parsers` package which contains `Parser` class which extends `BaseParser` class with `parse` method where is the custom code.

Then I add `import` into `__init__.py` file so it looks like this:

```
from feeds_core.parsers.parser__source1 import Parser as ParserForSource1
from feeds_core.parsers.parser__source2 import Parser as ParserForSource2
from feeds_core.parsers.parser__source3 import Parser as ParserForSource3

PARSER__SOURCE1 = 'source1'
PARSER__SOURCE2 = 'source2'
PARSER__SOURCE3 = 'source3'



CHOICES = {
    PARSER__SOURCE1: ParserForSource1,
    PARSER__SOURCE2: ParserForSource2,
    PARSER__SOURCE3: ParserForSource3,
}


def get_parser(choice):
    return CHOICES[choice]
```

Then I have a model `Source` with this field:

```
PARSER_CHOICES = [(x, x) for x in CHOICES.keys()]

parser = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=PARSER_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

def get_parser(self):
    ...
    elif self.parser:
        return self.get_parser_class()(self.get_last_filepaths(), self.user_eshop, self)
    else:
        raise self.NoParserDefinedException

def parse(self):  # TODO raise spec exc
    self.parse_started()
    self.get_parser().parse()
    self.parse_ended()

def get_parser_class(self) -> BaseParser:
    return get_parser(self.parser)
```

And when there is a new feed, I create the file, modify the `__init__.py` and choose the parser for this source in the `Django` admin interface.

But it is little bit complicated and moreover, I'm afraid I have to restart production server every time.

Do you have any ideas/experiences? Is there some best practice how to do such things?

Comment: Why not create a `Parser` model that you create instances of instead of modifying a file? How complex are these parsers and who will be uploading them? You can use some kind of file field to upload the script if you trust whoever is uploading them. Or use the FilePathField to select the file that you have added to the server You can use some kind of file field to upload the script

Comment: There are many ways that parsing can be specific so I can't just do it on DB level. I need custom code but one method is enough. Yes, I'm thinking about the FilePathField of FileField. But how to use the class from the uploaded script?

Answer (score 0):

A very basic implementation where you would add a file to a directory (`settings.PARSER_FILE_DIR`), it would then be an available choice for `Source.parser_file`, then using [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) you would load the file and extract the `Profile` class out of it. `settings.PARSER_FILE_DIR` would probably have to be in your `PYTHONPATH`

This is an extremely basic example and you would need a lot of error handling and would need to make sure it was very secure

```
import importlib

class Source(models.Model):

    parser_file = models.FilePathField(path=settings.PARSER_FILE_DIR, match='.*\.py$')

    def get_parser_class(self):
        return importlib.import_module(self.parser_file.replace('.py', '')).Parser
```